# What is the difficulty/advantage to obfuscate a multi-thread program?

Tags: obfuscation, deobfuscation, multi-process

According to my knowledge, several obfuscation strategies are widely used(or at least described in academic) like:

- complicating control flow

  1. inserting bogus control-flow
  2. control-flow flattening
  3. jump through branch functions
  4. opaque values from array aliasing
- Opaque Predicates

  1. opaque predicates from pointer aliasing
- dynamic obfuscation

  1. self-modifying state machine
  2. code as key material

From the examples they give when introducing these obfuscation ways, multi-thread program has not been talked.

So I am wondering whether these strategies are feasible(or even feasible, but not very practical) in multi-thread programs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them are feasible. 
By definition obfuscating code transformation is transformation that preserves functional equivalency of obfuscated program, so there is no any difference between multi-thread and single-thread programs from this point of view.